# Multiple Layers Boundless Suite-SDK ol3view

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite, sdk

I am currently building a simple web application with the Boundless OpenGeoSuite SDK ol3view (Openlayer3 viewer) and I was able to get one layer to show up from my geoserver instance but I would like to know how to show more than just one layer.  This is the code in the app.js that I have so far of the layer showing right now. The other layers are in the same workspace on geoserver with varying geometry field types.

```
// ========= config section ================================================
var url = '/geoserver/ows?';
var featurePrefix = 'Campus'; //workspace
var featureType = 'Basemap'; //layer name
var featureNS = 'Campus1'; //namespace
var srsName = 'EPSG:900913'; //projection
var geometryName = 'the_geom'; //geometry type
var geometryType = 'MultiLineString'; //field type
var fields = ['layer']; //columns
var layerTitle = 'layer';
var infoFormat = 'application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1'; // can also be 'text/html'
var center = [-10764594.758211, 4523072.3184791];
var zoom = 3;
```

// =========================================================================

Does anyone have an example in the code for the app.js that would show how to add multiple layers and or a group layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to repeat some of the code to get more than 1 layer, such as:

1) create another ol.source.TileWMS and set your layer name in the params (https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client/ol3view/src/app/app.js#L42:L47)

2) create another ol.layer.Tile and link to your source from step 1 (https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client/ol3view/src/app/app.js#L117:L120)

If you want GetFeatureInfo to work on multiple layers you will need to do some additional work, this has been discussed on ol3-dev (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/getfeatureinfo/ol3-dev/a0c1L3-92nY/VM6ehW5jIMQJ and https://gist.github.com/bartvde/43a3b8c9cf8798e16748)

Comment: I'm still just learning Javascript so your advice was helpful. I was looking at your code for the popups but haven't yet figured that part out yet, but I posted the code I have thus far just for posterity's sake if anyone else needs it for a simple reference. https://github.com/HerbFargus/Open-Geo-Suite-ol3view-SDK-examples/blob/master/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option is to make a " layer group " in Geoserver and consume that . In this method  you don't have to declare multiple layer .